# Unity Navmeshagent won't face the target object when reaches stopping distance

Tags: unity-game-engine, path-finding, navmesh

I'm trying to get the NPC to look at the main character when I'm talking to him. I need to make sure it looks natural and that he is facing me. I know I can do Transform.LookAt() but that is too instant and unnatural.

How do I rotate the navmeshagent to face my character when its stopped moving?

Answer (score 2):

Try this out to control the body orientation - the slerp is adjustable to your desired rotation speed (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html):

```
private void FaceTarget(Vector3 destination)
{
    Vector3 lookPos = destination - transform.position;
    lookPos.y = 0;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, [fill in desired rotation speed]);  
}
```

Comment: Not speed, but step

Answer (score 1):

```
if(agent.remainingDistance < agent.stoppingDistance) 
{
    agent.updateRotation = false;
    //insert your rotation code here
}
else {
    agent.updateRotation = true;
}
```

This will rotate your agent when it's distance below the stoppingDistance variable. However it will look inhuman, so if you're going for a humanoid ai I'd recommend looking at the unity [Mecanim demo](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/5328) (particularly the locomotion scene) as it has code and animations that will properly animate the agent.

Answer (score 0):

Put the char in a game object and copy the navmesh from the char to the parent, uncheck enable in char. move any scripts up too.
Just spent 5 hours to find this.